# Eclipse not able to create a zk-maven project

Tags: zk

While creating a zk-maven project i am getting an error .

In the catalog section after selecting ZK archetype 6.5.2 and then inserting the group id , Artifact Id ,version, package etc, it should populate "*properties available from archetype*" automatically.

But, in my case it does not happen.

Could anyone help me in this concern .

I have attached the screenshot here.[image]

ref: [here is the tutorial](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Installation%20Guide/Quick%20Start/Create%20and%20Run%20Your%20First%20ZK%20Application%20with%20Eclipse%20and%20Maven#cite_note-1)

Comment: Yes, thank you. I've seen this also but I don't have a solution. I suspect a bug in m2e. Do you see any errors in the "Error Log" view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting such error because **Eclipse Maven plugin** was trying to find the **ZK webapp archetype** from my local nexus repository.

ZK archetype remote catalog is located at

> http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2/

Add this url to

> C:\Users\.m2\settings.xml

.